# spring security with my own table

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security

I would ask a question  about spring security !!

is that possible to configure authentication-provide with my own table this is my exemple

tale "utilisateur"

```
CREATE TABLE utilisateur
(
  id_user serial NOT NULL,
  authority character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  username character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  "password" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT cl_primaire_utilisateur PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
)
```

haw can I do for making spring connect with my own table

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsService' />
    </authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JDBC-based user details service](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-jdbc-user-service) to achieve this. You can configure it to query arbitrary table for user and authorities.

Here is an example of the relevant security context section from one of my past projects that uses it:

```
<!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- DAO Based Security -->
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT U.username AS username, U.password as password, 'true' as enabled FROM user U where U.username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT U.username as username, A.name as authority FROM user U left join user_roles UA on U.id=UA.user left join role A on UA.roles = A.id WHERE U.username=?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```